# Problema al llamar un procedimiento mysql

Tags: mysql

Hice el siguiente procedimiento almacenado en mysql  el cual no me da error pero en el momento de hacer el llamado del procedimiento no me muestra los datos.

```
DELIMITER $$
create procedure procedimiento_1 (_FECHA int(20))
begin

select mascota.Nombre_Paciente Mascota, Nombre_Cliente cliente, Primer_Apellido Apellido,      Segundo_Apellido Apellido, Correo_Electronico Email, 
citas.Fecha Fecha, citas.HoraInicio Hora
from mascota
inner join cliente on mascota.IdCliente = cliente.IdCliente
inner join citas on mascota.IdMascota = citas.IdMascota
where _Fecha > '2020-09-02';

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Sera que esta mal el where? no buscas que la fecha en la tabla sea mayor al where? o menor? o lo que sea? pero comparando la tabla con el parametro?

Answer (score 0):

el tipo de dato que recibe el procedimiento "procedimiento_1" es un entero "int(20)", sin embargo, lo que deseas comparar es una fecha. Además, se debe indicar que el procedimiento recibe un dato con la palabra reservada "IN"

Con base a esto, deberías cambiar el tipo de dato que recibe el procedimiento a "DATE" y debes asegurar que el dato que se pase (desde el lenguaje de programación o por el usuario en consola) esté en este mismo formato "Y-mm-dd"

Ejemplo:

```
procedimiento_1 (IN _FECHA DATE)
```

Nota: aunque los Alias dentro de mysql son asignados por referencias es buena práctica indicarlos a través de la palabra reservada "AS".

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT mascota.Nombre_Paciente AS Mascota
```